# Run flutter app on iOS from android studio

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter

So I'm trying to build an app on flutter SDK using the android studio platform and now I want to run it on an iOS device. I've serched on google like 1h but I couldn't find anything(they only said how to run it on MAC which I don't have) . Is there any way how can I run the app from my android studio (or output the iOS app like the android app file which I can find in the project folder?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your asking how to run your app on a physical iOS device which you can find [on flutters website](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos) scroll down a little past half way and you will see a section called deploy to iOS devices. Since you don't have a mac testing on a physical device would be your only other option because you can not run a iOS simulator on anything but a mac computer. Gotta love apple :)
If you are without a mac there are some options to you. I will link to a couple articles below. Your best option is to get access to a mac I understand this isn't an option for everyone.
[How to sign Flutter apps for iOS automatically without a Mac](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-sign-flutter-apps-for-ios-automatically-without-a-mac-a2dc9cfa5a6c)
[Developing and debugging Flutter apps for iOS without a Mac](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-and-debugging-flutter-apps-for-ios-without-a-mac-8d362a8ec667)

Comment: I don't have an iPhone either. So maybe I should try to make an mac virtual machine and install the software and emulate an iPhone(my pc can't do that)?

Comment: I updated my post your options are limited but if this helps you please accept this answer :) apple is trying to force people to buy their products which is not fair.

Comment: Can you please accept this as the answer unless you have further questions :)

Comment: thanks for the no-mac links: very useful!!  :)